# What JVM checks in Java object equality (==)?

Tags: java

What does the JVM check in object equality (`==`)? Is it the `hashCode` of two objects or something else?

Answer (score 3):

The `==` operator *only* checks reference equality. It doesn't call any methods on the object... it just checks whether the two references involved are equal, i.e. they refer to the same object.

In simple cases I believe this is just a matter of comparing the references in a bitwise fashion - checking whether or not they consist of the same bytes. For more complex environments (e.g. ["compressed oops"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/performance-enhancements-7.html#compressedOop)) there could be slightly more work involved, in order to compare different representations. But the internally reference is *effectively* a pointer of some kind, and it's just a matter of comparing the two pointers.

Comment: true but what does JVM perform to check this reference equality on Object?

Comment: Jon Skeet responds to these questions too!! OMG!

Comment: @user1933888 That's how you teach this world. A question is a question. It could be dumb.

Comment: @Naresh: I never said the question is dumb, Happy Learning!

Comment: @user1933888 True you didn't say that. I just mean that its a very-very basic java question.

Comment: @user1933888: If you're asking about the JVM internal operations, that's *not* a "very-very basic java question". In terms of basics, you should view references as just opaque values which can either be `null` or refer to some object, and can be compared for equality. That's all you normally need to know about them. Why does it matter to you exactly how they're compared for equality? (Knowing that `==` *doesn't*  call `equals` or `hashCode` is important, but that's not the same thing.)

Comment: @user1933888 - Ya.. That's because he is still *slightly* mortal . Oh wait, I've seen his selfie with Zeus :P

Comment: @JonSkeet Ah. made me feel good. Many of us don't ask question because it looks so simple and get response 'oh that's a basic question'.

Answer (score 0):

The == is used to compare object references. It simply checks if the two object are pointing to the same reference.

Comment: @Naresh: what stops you from going into the source code to check the details?

Comment: I have tried my friend and ofcourse returning same hashCode for two objects doesn't return true which prompted me to ask this basic question.

Answer (score 0):

The equality operator (`==`) test for reference equality not `hashCode`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    MyClass obj1=new MyClass();

    MyClass obj2=new MyClass();   //obj1 and obj2 refers two different location

    System.out.println("obj1= "+obj1+"\tobj2="+obj2);
    if(obj1==obj2){   // so return false.
        System.out.println("obj1==obj2");
    }else{
        System.out.println("obj1!=obj2");
    }

    System.out.println(obj1.hashCode()+"\t"+obj2.hashCode());

    }

class MyClass{}
```

output:

```
obj1= com.think.test.MyClass@1e9cb75    obj2=com.think.test.MyClass@2c84d9
obj1!=obj2
hashCode
obj1=32099189   obj2=2917593
```

**EDIT**

```
class EqualityTest {

     @Override
     public int hashCode(){ 
         return 1; 
     } 
     public static void main(String... arg){
         EqualityTest t1 = new EqualityTest(); 
         EqualityTest t2 =t1;  // t2 referring to t1.
         System.out.println(t1); 
         System.out.println(t2); 
         System.out.println(t1.hashCode());
         System.out.println(t2.hashCode()); 
         System.out.println(t1==t2);  // so it return true.
         } 
}
```

output:

```
com.think.test.Test9@1
com.think.test.Test9@1
1
1
true
```

Comment: Just override hasCode() function and return constant integer. Even obj1 and obj2 will print same string representation with same hashCode value, still the objects are unequal.
See answer of @Jon Skeet which make sense that it might be comparing in bitwise fashion.

Comment: try `EqualityTest t2 =t1;` instead of `EqualityTest t2=new EqualityTest()` and check how `==` it works. hope it is clear.

Comment: since `t2` refers the same reference i.e `t1` so it return true.

Comment: This is a different test case scenario. Since t1 and t2 are referring to same object, it will definitely return true.

Comment: that's it. It clearly indicates that equality operator checks for  whether the objects pointing to same location/reference or different.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to see how JVM treats `==` at bytecode level.

For example

```
public boolean compare(Object o1, Object o2)
{
     return o1 == o2;
}
```

compiles to the following byte code instructions (use `javap -c` to generate this):

```
public boolean compare(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object);
  Code:
    0: aload_1
    1: aload_2
    2: if_acmpne     7
    5: iconst_1
    6: ireturn
    7: iconst_0
    8: ireturn
```

`aload1` and `aload2` load the references of o1 and o2 on the stack.
The `==` operation is performed by `if_acmpne`.

> if_acmpne pops the top two **object references** off the stack and
>   compares them. **If the two object references are not equal (i.e. if
>   they refer to different objects)**, execution branches to .... If the object
>   references refer to the same object, execution continues at the next
>   instruction.

Of course this doesn't tell you how the JVM interpreter implements object references, or how a bytecode to native compiler like Hotspot implements it, but its a good start to explore the topic.